# How to move touches from UIScrollView to UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, hittest, touches

I have a UITableView->UITableViewCells->UIScrollView hierarchy. If I tap on my cell, hitTest says that the touch is in the UIScrollView, and if I scroll - it also apperas to be in the UIScrollView. How can I make the touch be at the UITableViewCell level, but the scroll be at the UIScrollView level?

Comment: Do I understand you right: You have a `UIScrollView` inside of a `UITableViewCell`? If so, did you add it as a subView to the `contentsView` of the cell?

Comment: It's right and scrollView is subview of UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but it is unfortunately too long:

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) say:

> Because a scroll view has no scroll bars, it must know whether a touch
>   signals an intent to scroll versus an intent to track a subview in the
>   content. To make this determination, it temporarily intercepts a
>   touch-down event by starting a timer and, before the timer fires,
>   seeing if the touching finger makes any movement. If the timer fires
>   without a significant change in position, the scroll view sends
>   tracking events to the touched subview of the content view. If the
>   user then drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses, the
>   scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and performs the
>   scrolling itself.

So, are you sure that you added your `UIScrollView` as a subview to the `contentView` of your table view cell, and not to the cell itself?

Comment: but it's impossible to add scroll view not at the content view. Screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/woc279ngzprbvid/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202018-08-08%20%D0%B2%2021.16.52.png?dl=0

Comment: `UITableViewCell` inherits from `UIView`, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell), i.e. you could have added your scroll view directly to the cell as a subView. But since you haven't done so, my answer is obsolete, sorry.